# What is a clustermug?

Tags: meaning, obscure-terms

What is a clustermug? I could not find the word in a dictionary.

> Duke stopped laughing, but he was still smiling. Unabashed. "It's a clustermug," he said.

The quote is from the novel *Under the Dome* by Stephen King.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found this explanation:

> In Stephen King's 2009 novel Under the Dome, the character 'Big Jim' Rennie avoids swearing by replacing words such as fucking and clusterfuck with cottonpicking and clustermug.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oaths_in_media)</sub>